# Multiple Object Detection shows single blob in binary image

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on pool ball tracking and detection with an IR camera using OpenCV in C++. I am able to segment the ball as blobs in a Binary image. The problem occurs when multiple pool balls are touching each other. The algorithm considers it as a single large blob. I have tried :

1. Various parameters for erosion and dilation.
2. Distance transform and watershed algorithm.
3. Convexity Defects.
   Can someone please give suggestions for the same?

Sample Blob Image:

[image]

Comment: Is the camera always in the same position? Just define the exact size if a single ball. If a ball region is about N x bigger than that defined size, split it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the camera is fixed. Can you please tell me how to split a blob in N equal sub blobs?